# How to create gmail-like recipient (user) custom view

Tags: android, gmail, android-custom-view

My goal is to create this badge-like view used in Gmail and Foursquare as given below.

[image]

So far I have created `ReplacementSpan` to handle foreground and background color of individual view.

```
public class SearchTagSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

    private int backgroundColor;
    private int forgroundColor;

    public SearchTagSpan() {
        backgroundColor = -1;
        forgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
    }

    public SearchTagSpan(int backgroundColor, int forgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.forgroundColor = forgroundColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(
            Canvas canvas,
            CharSequence text, int start, int end,
            float x, int top, int y, int bottom,
            Paint paint) {
        RectF rect = new RectF(x, top, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom);
        paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
        paint.setColor(forgroundColor);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(
            Paint paint,
            CharSequence text, int start, int end,
            Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));
    }

    private float measureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
        return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    }
}
```

Both background and foreground color is applied correctly however when the view becomes multiple-line the background of each badge stretch to fill the line spacing specified in the `TextView` layout. If I remove line spacing then the background of the first and second line are touching each other as shown in the image below.

[image]

Am I going the right direction here? Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at these

https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/WUd7GrfZfiZ
and
https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete
and 
https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I should have remembered I read about this somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For that you need ActionBar. 
This supports above +3.0

If you need same in lower version of android then you can use appCompat support library in order to support lower version of android.

Kindly refer .. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

and best working example tutorial over here ... http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The question was about the chip in TO: box and not the ActionBar. Sorry if I confused you.